# Threshold on triangular SparseArray

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I am confused by the behavior of `Threshold` on sparse `UpperTringularize` (and `LowerTringularize`).

Take the following example:

```
SeedRandom[123];
mat = 10^-# &@RandomReal[{0, 25}, {5, 5}];
matS = SparseArray[mat];
MatrixForm[mat]
```

[image]

Applying `UpperTriangularize` keeping and discarding the diagonal:

```
tmp1 = UpperTriangularize[matS, 1];
tmp  = UpperTriangularize[matS];
```

I want to keep the `n=3` largest row entries:

```
Map[Threshold[#, {"LargestValues", n}] &, matS] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

This also works on the full upper triangle:

```
Map[Threshold[#, {"LargestValues", 3}] &, tmp] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

But it doesn't work on the upper triangle missing the diagonal throwing a `Threshold::nlist` error:

```
Map[Threshold[#, {"LargestValues", 3}] &, tmp1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Applying the same on the dense matrix works:

```
Map[Threshold[#, {"LargestValues", 3}] &, UpperTriangularize[mat, 1]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

What is going on here? Is this a bug in `SparseArray`?

Comment: Many functions for `SparseArray`s operate only on the nonzero values. So `Threshold[tmp1[[5]], {"LargestValues", 3}]` is probably redirected to `Threshold[tmp1[[5]]["NonzeroValues"], {"LargestValues", n}]` and the latter evaluates to `Threshold[{}, {"LargestValues", n}]`. This is certainly not correct, but it is easy to overlook when implementing things like this. Please report Wolfram Support about this. For the moment you can circumvent this issue by first checking your `SparseArrays` before handing them over to `Threshold`.